# C# client communication Via UPD

Tags: c#, udp, communication, udpclient, visual-c#-express-2010

I am looking for some help with communication between my server application and my client.The idea is that my client will listen for a UDP packet, read it and then execute a command based on what it reads.

My issue is that the server sends the packet however the client does nothing.
Here is a snippet of my code:

Client:

```
public void listen()
{
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show("");

            UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(11000);


            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);
            try
            {

                // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
                Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

                string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
                string[] split = returnData.Split(':');

                if (split[0] == "SayHello")
                {
                  MessageBox.show("Hello user","Hello"); 
                }

                //Note i have many commands but i shortened it to save room. 

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
}
```

Server:

```
else if (radioButton4.Checked)
{
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient([IP_ADDRESS_HERE], 11000);
            body = richTextBox1.Text;
            title = textBox1.Text;
            Command = "Message" + ":" + body + ":" + title + ":" + 4;
            Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Command);

            try
            {
                udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Just wanted to see if you guys are able to find something I overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Windows Firewall and verify it's not blocking your Client from opening port 11000.
Control Panel-> System and Security -> Windows Firewall